# How to add Element to 3 dimensional ArrayList? - Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to add a `String` to a specific location in an `ArrayList` that looks like this:

```
ArrayList <String[][]> arrayList3D = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arrayString3D));
```

I tried this out:

```
arrayList3D.get(0).get(1).add("new Word");
```

but it didn't work...

Comment: *"but it didn't work"* - what does that mean? Did you get an error? If so, which?

Comment: `String.get[0]` is an array not a list

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Comment: This isn't my homework!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man, first you should create an array and later the another. try this.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>  arrayList3D = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

Later, you should create the another.

```
arrayList3D.add(0, new ArrayList<String>());
```

but you show that you want to do this.

```
arrayList3D.get(0).get(1).add("new Word");
```

The problem here is that does it exist a value in that position. It does, it works, but, it doesn't.. you should write this.

```
ArrayList3D.get(0).add(1, "value to input");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close but not quite correct.

The process goes as follows:

`arrayList3D.get(0)` regardless of the index provided ( `0` or greater) will return a 2D array i.e `String[][]`.

so in order to access a particular position of the 2D array, you'll need to use 2 pairs of square brackets one indicating the row and another indicating the column.

i.e

```
arrayList3D.get(0)[1][0] = "new Word";
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array`s in Java don't provide `get` methods. An equivalent is given by *bracket notation*. You set the element at index `i` like:

```
array[i] = value;
```

Your `ArrayList` contains elements of type `String[][]` which are **arrays** that contain other arrays that hold `String` elements.

So a correct access would look like:

```
arrayList3D.get(0)[1][i] = "new Word";
```

Where `i` is the position you want to add the element in the last array.

Maybe this view helps more:

```
arrayList3D  // ArrayList<String[][]>
    .get(0)  // String[][]
    [1]      // String[]
    [i]      // String
        = "new Word";
```

If you want to have `get` methods and be able to dynamically add elements, you would need something like `ArrayList<List<List<String>>>` instead since **arrays** are of **fixed size**.

You could do it by manually converting your `String[][][]` to `List<List<List<String>>>`, for example by using regular loops:

```
List<List<List<String>>> arrayList3D = new ArrayList<>();
// Traverse all 2-dim elements
for (String[][] dim2Arr : arrayString3D) {
    List<List<String>> arrayList2D = new ArrayList<>();
    // Traverse all 1-dim elements
    for (String[] dim1Arr : dim2Arr) {
        List<String> arrayList1D = Arrays.asList(dim1Arr);

        // Add 1-dim to 2-dim
        arrayList2D.add(arrayList1D);
    }

    // Add 2-dim to 3-dim
    arrayList3D.add(arrayList2D);
}
```

Comment: How should I initialize `ArrayList<List<List<String>>>`?  It doesn't work this way:  `ArrayList<List<List<String>>> arrayList3D = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arrayString3D));` I get this error:  `Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<String[][]> to ArrayList<List<List<String>>>`

Comment: @Andy Yeah, since `arrayString3D` is of type `String[][][]`, `Arrays.asList` only converts the top array-layer to `List`. The simplest would be to manually collect every layer to a `List`, for example using simple loops. I've edited the answer to show you how.